# Solr autocommit and autooptimize?

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, solr

I will be uploading my website to a VPS soon. It is a classifieds website which uses **Solr** integrated with MySql.

Solr is updated whenever a new classified is put or deleted.

I need a way to make the `commit()` and `optimize()` be automated, for example once every 3 hours or so.

How can I do this? (Details Please)
When is it ideal to optimize?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set up a cron task that periodically executes a remote call to the Solr REST interface, e.g:

```
curl 'http://<SOLR_INSTANCE_URL>/update?optimize=true'
```

Find further info on updating the Solr index [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22).

Quoting the [Solr tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html):

> Commit can be an expensive operation
>   so it's best to make many changes to
>   an index in a batch and then send the
>   commit command at the end. There is
>   also an optimize command that does the
>   same thing as commit, in addition to
>   merging all index segments into a
>   single segment, making it faster to
>   search and causing any deleted
>   documents to be removed.

**UPDATE:**
Besides, the auto-commit feature can be enabled in solrconfig.xml (within the `UpdateHandler` section):

```
<autoCommit>
      <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs> <!-- maximum uncommited docs before autocommit triggered -->
      <maxTime>86000</maxTime> <!-- maximum time (in MS) after adding a doc before an autocommit is triggered -->
</autoCommit>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is a follow-up Q, does optimize also perform commit? So when doing only optimize it also commits? Thanks

Comment: Yes, optimize performs commit plus merging all index segments into a single segment (a new segment is created when a new writer is opened and when a writer commits or is closed).